# Scheduling tasks with a maximum / minimum duration between tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, scheduledexecutorservice

Refreshing records from a DB. We either get an explicit notification to refresh, or poll every 60 seconds. No more than one refresh per second.

If a request comes in, it should queue an immediate refresh if one has not happened within one second. Otherwise, it should schedule a refresh for 1 second after the end of the last refresh, unless such a task is already scheduled for that time or sooner.

After one minute without an explicit refresh, the timer should kick in and refresh, in case notifications were not sent.

There may be a large number of notifications coming in (several hundred per second).

Refreshing can be done by a separate single thread.

What's an elegant way to design this?

Here's what I have, but it might lead to too many requests:

```
private NotificationCenter() {
    recordFetchService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    recordFetchService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(refreshCommand, minTimeBetweenRefresh, maxTimeBetweenRefresh, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

private void queueRefresh() {
    // explicit refresh requested. Schedule a refreshCommand to fire immediately, unless that would break our contract
    if (!pending.isDone() && pending.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) < minTimeBetweenRefresh) {
        // a refresh is already scheduled
    } else {
        pending = recordFetchService.schedule(refreshCommand, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With "hundreds of notifications per second" an `AtomicBoolean` comes to mind to switch state exactly once from "doing nothing" to "going to do something" and vice versa. Couple the "going to do something" state with a `Semaphore` and you have the option to determine the exact moment when "going to do something" takes place.

Below a (runnable) example implementation/design that combines the `AtomicBoolean` and `Semaphore` to refresh data regularly while using notifications. It is probably not the most elegant way, but I do think it accomplishes the goal in a relative straightforward manner.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class RefreshTask {

    private static final long MIN_WAIT_MS = 100L;
    private static final long MAX_WAIT_MS = 1000L;

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private volatile boolean stopping; 

    private final Semaphore refreshLock = new Semaphore(0);
    private final AtomicBoolean refreshing = new AtomicBoolean();
    private volatile long lastRefresh;

    public void start() {

        stopping = false;
        refreshing.set(true);
        lastRefresh = System.currentTimeMillis();
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(new RefreshLoop());
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    }

    public void stop() {

        stopping = true;
        if (executor != null) {
            refreshLock.release();
            scheduler.shutdownNow();
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    }

    /** Trigger a (scheduled) refresh of data. */
    public void refresh() {

        if (refreshing.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            final long dataAge = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastRefresh;
            if (dataAge >= MIN_WAIT_MS) {
                refreshLock.release();
                // println("Refresh lock released.");
            } else {
                long waitTime = MIN_WAIT_MS - dataAge;
                scheduler.schedule(new RefreshReleaser(), waitTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                println("Refresh scheduled in " + waitTime + " ms.");
            }
        } else {
            // println("Refresh already triggered.");
        }
    }

    protected void refreshData() {

        // Refresh data from database
        println("DATA refresh");
    }

    class RefreshLoop implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (!stopping) {
                try {
                    refreshData();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                lastRefresh = System.currentTimeMillis();
                refreshing.set(false);
                try {
                    if (!refreshLock.tryAcquire(MAX_WAIT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                        if (!refreshing.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                            // Unlikely state, but can happen if "dataAge" in the refresh-method is around MAX_WAIT_MS.
                            // Resolve the race-condition by removing the extra permit.
                            if (refreshLock.tryAcquire()) {
                                println("Refresh lock race-condition detected, removed additional permit.");
                            } else {
                                println("Refresh lock race-condition detected, but no additional permit found.");
                            }
                        }
                        println("Refreshing after max waiting time.");
                    } // else refreshing already set to true
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    if (!stopping) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            println("Refresh loop stopped.");
        }
    }

    class RefreshReleaser implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (refreshing.get()) {
                refreshLock.release();
                println("Scheduled refresh lock release.");
            } else {
                println("Programming error, scheduled refresh lock release can only be done in refreshing state.");
            }
        }
    }

    /* *** some testing *** */

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RefreshTask rt = new RefreshTask();
        try {
            println("Starting");
            rt.start();
            Thread.sleep(2 * MIN_WAIT_MS);
            println("Triggering refresh");
            rt.refresh();
            Thread.sleep(MAX_WAIT_MS + (MIN_WAIT_MS / 2));
            println("Triggering refresh 2");
            rt.refresh();
            Thread.sleep(MIN_WAIT_MS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            rt.stop();
        }
    }

    public static final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public static void println(String msg) {
        println(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime, msg);
    }

    public static void println(long tstamp, String msg) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%05d ", tstamp) + msg);
    }

}
```